# Remove escape characters from String loaded from file

Tags: java, file

I am using the below method to load a string from file to variable.

```
private static String readFile(String path) throws IOException {
  FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
  try {
    FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
    MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
    /* Instead of using default, pass in a decoder. */
    return Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
  }
  finally {
    stream.close();
  }
}
```

The problem is that my variable has escape characters in it. I want my variables to contain:

`some string`

but instead it looks like:

`some string&#xd`

how can i improve my method to not allow that?

Comment: `&#xd` this is added at the end of each line.

Comment: Are you trying to read from an xml file?

Comment: @GrzegorzS: Can `&#xd` occur anywhere else, or do you just need to replace every occurrence of it with `""`?

Comment: do the contents of text file contain tags as in xml?

Comment: I want my variable to look *exactly the same* like content of my `.txt` file, which means i don't want any `&#xd` in it.

Comment: @Sibrajas no. Content of the file doesn't even contain single markup nor `<` sign or `>`

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using a `FileChannel` and a `MappedByteBuffer`?

Comment: @Duncan Jones to be honest `FileChannel` and `MappedByteBuffer` worked well for me in the past and i believe that using it instead of `StringBuilder` is much more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Reader instead, and BufferedReader in particular to read lines from TXT file:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
String line = br.readLine(); // this strips line termination characters for you
```

If you want to read the whole file, there are lots of utility classes that provide this functionality (like Google Guava):

```
String contents = Files.toString(new File(path), charset);
```

Comment: `some text` is the example of the file content. My file have many lines, which make me use string builder right?

Comment: if you want to preserve termination characters, you can use Reader#read(char[] buf, 0, fileSize) and then convert it to String

Answer (score 0):

I would think that there are some hidden characters in your `.txt` file.

You could try:

```
return Charset.defaultCharset()
   .newDecoder()
   .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE)
   .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE)
   .decode(bb)
   .toString()
```

Comment: error `The method onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction) is undefined for the type Charset`